# How to make Laravel (Sail) handle requests asynchronously

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laravel-9, laravel-sail

I have been having this issue on multiple devices, with both Sail and artisan serve:

I have a basic controller like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    function test($id) {
        if ($id == 1) {
            sleep(45);
        }

        return 'Hello World';
    }
}
```

with this in my web.php route file:

```
Route::controller(Controller::class)->group(function () {
    Route::get('/test/{id}', 'test');
});
```

Then, in Chrome I will go to `localhost/test/1` and immediately go to `localhost/test/2` in Firefox. In chrome, the tab will sit and wait for 45 seconds before loading as expected. However, Firefox will also wait until the Chrome script finishes before it loads. If you visit `localhost/test/2` without visiting the other first, it loads instantly as expected.

What is going on? Why is one script blocking all others, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Maybe because of `sleep()`  function

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I have tried it with a loop just decrementing a large number, in case sleep was causing the issue, same result. Sleep does not cause this issue in vanilla PHP either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the .env file:

```
PHP_CLI_SERVER_WORKERS=3
```

Confirmed that it works.
Don't forget to restart Sail.

Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/can-laravel-sail-only-handle-one-request-at-a-time